# Upload vs. Download vs. Artifacts

Tags: github, github-actions

I have an action which runs a program and that program generates a file graph.png.

I would like to have that file appear in the same GitHub repo so that it is available to me when I git pull.

The polarity and functionality of artifact upload and download is confusing. What am I uploading? From what to what? What am I downloading?

Comment: If a file was "there" and now it is "here", it's a download. If a file was "here" and now it is "there", it's an upload.

Comment: I like that formulation...

Comment: Someone missed the part where the file is in one part of github and then it's in another part of github. From the perspective of the individual they are both "there"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation "[Persisting workflow data using artifacts](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/persisting-workflow-data-using-artifacts)" gives some clues:

> Artifacts allow you to persist data after a job has completed.
>   An artifact is a file or collection of files produced during a workflow run.
>   You can use artifacts to pass data between jobs in a workflow or persist build and test output after a workflow run has ended

But:

> GitHub stores artifacts for 90 days for pushes and pull requests.
>   (The retention period for a pull request restarts each time someone pushes new commits to the pull request.)

So:

- said artifact might not always be there when you pull.
- said artifact won't be in the same repository, but is stored elsewhere, and is associated to job (action) execution.

You might rather create a release [`actions/create-release`](https://github.com/actions/create-release) and store your artifact as a release asset.

Like artifact, it won't exactly appear in the same GitHub repository, [but it can be queried](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset), through its asset ID ([listed from the release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-assets-for-a-release))

---

To truly add a new files, you would need the ["Add & Commit" GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-commit)

That would ensure a future clone or pull of your repository would include the file you want.

Comment: I read and re-read that and was still confused... Ok, so is an artifact different from a file in my GitHub repo?

Comment: @pitosalas I confirm: artifact (associated to job executions) and assets (associated to a release) are *not* "files in your repositories.

Comment: @pitosalas I have added an action which should be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That link led me to this: https://github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action which is what I am using. So.. an artifact is a by product of an action which lives for a while to allow it to be used by another action. But it is stored somewhere other than the actual repo. And uploading creates a new artifact during the running of an action, and downloading brings the artifact into an action's context so that it can be used. Sound right?